# Show Dupe Values

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code currently:

SELECT e.AUDIT_ID, s.USER_ID, s.AUD_ID
FROM USERS_123 e, USERS s
WHERE e.USER_ID = s.USER_ID

Results:

e.AUDIT_ID|s.USER_ID, |    s.AUD_ID

2222389      abcdef0192     2222389
2222400     abcdef0203      2222400
2222399     abcdef0202      2222399
2222398     abcdef0201      2222398
2222397     abcdef0200      2222397

What I would like to find out is:

Dupe values in Col e.AUDIT_ID of the results above (if any)
Something that would show say this type of duping:

**2222389   abcdef019   2222389**
**2222389   abcdef019   2222389**
**2222389   abcdef019   2222389**
2222388    abcdef0191    22222388
2222387    abcdef0190    22222387

Comment: Show - where? In the same query, additional column?

Comment: To add to @mathguy's question, since you're joining, you could also get "duplicates" just from having multiple rows in `USERS` related to the same row in `USERS_123`, but this wouldn't represent a duplicate row in `USERS_123`. Please clarify exactly what you mean by "duplicates."

Comment: Next time when you are making changes to your question, do it in latest version.

Comment: was just clarifying what I was after, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATED:*

```
SELECT e.AUDIT_ID, s.USER_ID, s.AUD_ID
FROM USERS_123 e, USERS s
WHERE e.USER_ID = s.USER_ID
GROUP BY e.AUDIT_ID, s.USER_ID, s.AUD_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To get any duplicate `AUDIT_ID` that exists (Old Response):

```
SELECT audit_id
FROM users_123
GROUP BY audit_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Please see revised post - adding the group by and having to the end of the query throws error. Any suggestion?

Comment: SELECT e.AUDIT_ID, s.USER_ID, s.AUD_ID
FROM USERS_123 e, USERS s
WHERE e.USER_ID = s.USER_ID
GROUP BY e.audit_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 - "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Oracle return `ORA-00979` because everything you are selecting from the table should be in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Could you give a sample data of USERS_123 and USERS table? It would be so much easier to understand.

Comment: @ pthfndr2007 Try:
SELECT e.AUDIT_ID, s.USER_ID, s.AUD_ID
FROM USERS_123 e, USERS s
WHERE e.USER_ID = s.USER_ID GROUP BY e.AUDIT_ID, s.USER_ID, s.AUD_ID having count(*) > 1

This will return:
2222389   abcdef019   2222389

Is that what you are looking for or
2222389   abcdef019   2222389
2222389   abcdef019   2222389
2222389   abcdef019   2222389
2222389   abcdef019   2222389
?

Comment: perfect - that is what I needed! Thank you.

Comment: Glad you found what you are looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate `AUDIT_ID`?. Well, group by that ID and count:

```
SELECT audit_id 
FROM users_123
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```